# How to manually start a OrientGraph transaction?

Tags: transactions, gremlin, orientdb

I'm using OrientDB, with OrientGraph.
This kind of db open a new transaction at first operation executed by default.
There is a parameter named `blueprints.orientdb.autoStartTx` that is `true` by default.

I want to manually manage graph operations, so i set it to `false` (means all operations are atomic) but i can't find a method to manual start a new transaction, only `commit()` and `rollback()` are provided.

What should i call to manually start a new transaction?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
graph.getRawGraph().begin()
```